# Vue3 init variable with props

Tags: vuejs3, vue-props

```
const props = defineProps({
a: Object
})

function calcs() {
var b = props.a;
b.push({
xxx: yyy
});
}
```

e.g. a={x: 'y'}

I need `b` to be `{x: 'y'}` before `b.push` each time when call function `calcs`, but `b` keep pushing `xxx:yyy`, any solutions? I tried `ref(props.a)`, `reactive(props.a)`, still not working.

1st call `calcs`, the output is:

```
props.a={x: 'y'}  
b={x: 'y',xxx: 'yyy'}
```

2nd call `calcs`, the output become:

```
props.a={x: 'y',xxx: 'yyy'}  
b={x: 'y',xxx: 'yyy',xxx: 'yyy'}
```

3rd call `calcs`, the output become:

```
props.a={x: 'y',xxx: 'yyy',xxx: 'yyy'}  
b={x: 'y',xxx: 'yyy',xxx: 'yyy',xxx: 'yyy'}
```

I have no idea the prop a changes after each call, how can I get the output the same as the 1st call which is:

```
props.a={x: 'y'}  
b={x: 'y',xxx: 'yyy'}
```

Thanks, I'm new to Vue.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  if b needs to be "{x: 'y'}" then `var b = {x: 'y'}`.  and if "but b keep pushing xxx:yyy" is a problem then why do you push exactly that?  what do you want to push instead?

Comment: Thanks for reply, the values {x: 'y'} and {xxx: 'yyy'} are dynamic, what I need to is pass  props.a to b each time before b.push. :-(

Answer (score 0):

var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.a)) fixed the issue.